# Solution Verification for a Convergence Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

**The Question**

Give an example of a pair of series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ with positive terms where the limit as n goes to infinity of $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$ and $b_n$ diverges and $a_n$ converges.

**My Solution**

$a_n = 1/n^2$

$b_n = n^2$

This was supposed to be one of the harder questions on the assignment and seemed too easy. Did I mess up anywhere?

Comment: But $\frac{a_n}{b_n}= \frac {1/n^2}{n^2}=1$...

Comment: Hmmmm but if we do the limit as n goes to infinity doesn't the top go to 0 and the bottom go to infinity?

Comment: @PassingBy, Unless I am not awake right now, I thought $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{1}{n^4}$

Comment: @PassingBy I think you're tripping, (1/4/4 = .25/4 =/= 1)

Comment: @Dunka: My apologies, you are correct.

Comment: @Dunka, your counterexample looks fine on my part.

Comment: @PassingBy No problem man.